# Converting Text field to currency in Apex

Tags: apex

Need to Converting Text field to currency in Apex:

```
String Amount = '989898.67'
```

was trying out something like :

```
    String s = ( Decimal.valueOf(i==null||i.trim()==”?’0′:i).setScale(2) + 0.001 ).format();
    String p = s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
```

Question - What all considerations that needs to mae about data integrity ?
Any direct function available ?

Comment: Discussions have been had on [What is a concise function that formats a (String) decimal into a currency format in Apex?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318/what-is-a-concise-function-that-formats-a-string-decimal-into-a-currency-forma). Really good points made here on locales and precision.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a formatted string version of a Decimal (currency) value is surprisingly difficult in Apex - see [Apex - format number with more than 3 digits after decimal point](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99298/apex-format-number-with-more-than-3-digits-after-decimal-point).

But if you want the value as a number for calculations, then as you probably already know the `Decimal` class has all the [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm%23apex_System_Decimal_methods) you need to control the scale and rounding of the conversion:

```
Decimal d = Decimal.valueOf(!String.isEmpty(amount) ? amount : '0');
d = d.setScale(8, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```